# AIDE Creating A New Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

Well I've been askin around bout just can't get my head around this. I have AIDE and use it to learn android app development. Now,I have started a new project in aide.
It's the main activity is like a welcome screen to the user. It display some text & a button (continue). Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/image_1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="myText"
        android:paddingLeft="80dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/mainTextView1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="myText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/mainTextView2"
        android:textColor="#0EFF08"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="myText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainTextView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/mainTextView3"
        android:textColor="#E7E705"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="myText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainTextView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/mainTextView4"
        android:textColor="#FF1702"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainTextView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onContinueButtonClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I need an example or some help. When the user tap the button it should open a new activity consisting of a listView with an image and text next to each list item. How do I do this. I have downloaded a "GridView" example from github but its not what I want to implement into the second activity. Can someone please help me to understand how to create a new activity for the click of the button.

Comment: This is XML code. It is used only for the UI. If you want to do things like opening a new Activity, and even manipulating this view you should start looking for some code tutorials. AIDE is great, but check it out and make sure you're not avoiding some special part

Comment: @joaquin tnx. I know its got to do with the xml file. I just need a simple exapmle of what I wanto do with my app.

Comment: You want that we make your homework? Implementing a button listener is one thing. Implementing a button in an Activity A that opens an Activity B and that Activity B have a GridView in its related XML and another XML for each row representation and an adapter in the core of that Activity B that glues all of that and also a listener for the GridView... That's not what Stack Overflow will do for you

Comment: Ok thanks. Couldn't find the appropriate place to ask this thats why I asked here. Using the stack overflow app.

Comment: The point here is that your question is too broad.